# Wrong column type on hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

When I change the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value from `update` to`validate`, it gives me the error message:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in
>   public.element for column phaseFromA. Found: float4, expected: float

The field it is referencing for is:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
@Basic
private float phaseFromA;
```

and it was mapped into postgreSQL as a REAL type.
I've read that the solution is to put the columndefinition in the annotation, but it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Does it work with `double`?

Comment: I'm trying to change to.

Comment: @LeandroLima did you found the answer? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Erlan try to define the column type using @Column(columnDefinition = "FLOAT")

Comment: @LeandroLima I changed float to double, I will try it later. Thanks.